# Eclipse Oxigen delete line shortcut doesn't work

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE Oxigen 3A on a Linux Mint 18.3 with Cynnamon (new to Mint). I can't get the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut working while editing code. I can get to Windows -> Preferences -> Editor -> Keys and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> in the Binding field (Delete line is already bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>) but in editor that key combination has no effect. How to have back the Delete line shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This problem is not only related to Oxigen.

I had the same problem after deleting eclipse .metadata folder.
I found the answer after I saw the OP comment on this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900833/10889383

The "When" field was set to "Editing Text".
So I duped the "delete line" command with the "Copy Command" button and then switched the "When" field to "Editing Java Source".